# Walkthrough-Screens in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know this question is a part from research, but I couldn't find anything, since I don't even know what this is called:

With Android or/and iOS-Apps there is a possibility to create Walkthrough-Screens/In-App-Tutorial-Views. (the normal View, but with a gray layer in front of, only a few buttons enabled, and tutorial-text).

[image]

What is this called??

Or are there any frameworks for ASP.Net? (Doesn't matter how old, I could rewrite to MVC/Razor - would be a nice project, too.)

(Meanwhile, google blocks my search-queries. they think I'm a search-bot :D)

Comment: See [http://introjs.com/](http://introjs.com/), for example.

Comment: Instead of finding something in ASP.NET, You can go for http://introjs.com/. a jquery library. Its very easy to use and does a great job.

Comment: @AntonGogolev Please (!) post this as an answere. Totally, what I searched for. And what is it called? an intro-screen?

Comment: What's it called though? Otherwise this is just a shopping question "in app tutorials" - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/04/rethinking-mobile-tutorials-which-patterns-really-work/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called "Web Site Tours" or "Walkthroughs" or "Guided Tour" plugins and there are quite a few of them. In no particluar order (and no affiliation with the sites):

- http://introjs.com/
- [What tools can I use to create a guided tour (walkthrough) of my website?](https://www.quora.com/What-tools-can-I-use-to-create-a-guided-tour-walkthrough-of-my-website)
- [15 Best jQuery Site Tour Plugins](https://codegeekz.com/15-best-jquery-site-tour-plugins/)
- [25+ Free JQuery Plugins For Doing Guided Tours Through A Website](http://ninodezign.com/25-free-jquery-plugins-for-doing-guided-tours-through-a-website/)

Comment: Nice! Yeah my keywords were something like "Presentation" and "Layer" and something. But thats something else..